# mysql_Query date() error

Tags: mysql, date

I'm using a script to add reactions to my page.

$id is defined and works.
But still the script refuses to enter the data in the database.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO gastenboek (id, naam, bericht, datum, ip) VALUES ($id, '".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['naam']))."', '".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bericht']))."', date(d M Y, H:i), '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."')")) {
    echo '<span style="color:green; font-weight: bold"Je reactie is succesvol toegevoegd!</span>';
} else {
    echo '<span style="color:green; font-weight: bold">Er is iets fout gegaan en je reactie is niet toegevoegd. Probeer het later opnieuw.</span>';

}
```

I always get the 'else message' back.
Am I doing something wrong?

I'm guessing something is wrong with my date() function?
I want my date formated like this:
16 Mar 2016 - 20:33

Comment: Can you please post the result of this: `$qry = "INSERT INTO gastenboek (id, naam, bericht, datum, ip) VALUES ($id, '".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['naam']))."', '".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bericht']))."', date(d M Y, H:i), '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."')"; echo $qry;`

Comment: INSERT INTO gastenboek (id, naam, bericht, datum, ip) VALUES (14, '', '', date(d M Y, H:i), '94.226.201.228')

Comment: The problem is somewhere in my date function.
It works when I use
date(dMY)
But I get a 500 error when I use spaces
date(d M Y)

Comment: @Laurenz answer below resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `date(d M Y, H:i)` is a string so it needs to be quoted. When it is `date(dMY)` it is just an integer which doesn't need to be quoted.

Your format `date(d M Y, H:i)` isn't in `mysql`'s datetime format either. Datetime in mysql is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.
>
> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

So try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO gastenboek (id, naam, bericht, datum, ip) VALUES ($id, '".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['naam']))."', '".trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bericht']))."', '" . date(d M Y, H:i) . "', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."')")
```

Additional notes:

- You should update the driver you connect to your DB with, PDO or mysqli.
- You should use parameterized queries then quoting strings won't affect you.
- You should check your error logs and use the functions associated with the driver you are using to check for errors. For example with your current driver, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php